# XSP.partialRefreshGet - Not sending values and not triggering events

Tags: ajax, xpages, xpages-ssjs

Spent a couple of hours on this now and I'm at my end of the rope here...

Could someone please tell why the below isn't working:

Just created a fresh database on a Domino 8.5.3 server all default settings.

What I expect to happen is that "$$xspsubmitvalue" should contain "whatYouWantToSendHere", but it's empty.

I'm using the URL to open the XPage: `/fresh.nsf/test.xsp?Open&Login`

This is the request URL after pushing the button:

```
/fresh.nsf/test.xsp?Open&Login&$$ajaxid=view%3A_id1%3ArefreshMe
```

and this is the form data:

```
$$viewid:!d6g1y5acmu!

$$xspsubmitid:view:_id1:_id2

$$xspexecid:

**$$xspsubmitvalue:**

$$xspsubmitscroll:0|0

view:_id1:view:_id1
```

Would highly appreciate some input!

Thanks!

/J

SourceCode

http://pastebin.com/nyQYaRUC

Comment: Not only is the $$xspsubmitvalue empty but none of the events gets triggered!

Comment: I expect at least onStart and onComplete to trigger, but nothing. No JavaScript Errors either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first, I believe you have an extra ",{}" in there at the end of the call to the partialRefreshGet function - partialRefreshGet only takes two parameters, the ID and the options object, but that isn't your issue.

The problem is that you have this is all happening inside a button that is also doing a partial refresh - since partial refreshes are asynchronous, and only one partial refresh can happen at a time, your code to execute the partial is conflicting with the button click's action to do a partial. Set submit="false" on your button and see if it works.

Comment: Got a bit carried away with my copy pasting trying to solve another problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Not completely true - by using *XSP.allowSubmit()* you can run multiple partial refreshs at one time. SCNR :-)

Comment: @Sven :) - Very true - you could change the default rules to create a new circumstance

Answer (score 2):

The code of your button is "corrupt": It fires a partial refresh, and the CSJS code will never be executed.

Change this

```
<xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial"
        refreshId="refreshMe">
```

to this

```
<xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
```

then it will work as required.

**EDIT**

Normal CSJS code will be executed, but not the CSJS based partial refresh because of an internal blocking ( a timestamp stored in XSP.lastSubmit ).

Comment: Not completely true - the CSJS code will actually be firing, but its getting called during the firing of the button's event - since it is set to submit="true" the button's partial refresh is already considered "in progress", preventing any partial refresh from getting programmatically called during the CSJS side of the button's click event. So technically your solution is correct, but not for the reason you say.

Comment: What I mean is the CSJS triggered partial refresh.